# how to undeploy an application on my localhost

Tags: web-applications, hosting, localhost, web-hosting

Some application is running on my localhost on 8080 port.I don't know which application is running on that port.
If I run that on my browser, it will ask for the user credentials which i don't know as a result of which I cant know which app is running.. I want to undeploy that application.. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Open your IIS manager, there you can see what application is running there.

It is possible to host multiple application on port 8080, just create a virtual directory and you can have as many apps running as you want.

- localhost:8080/Web/App1
- localhost:8080/Web/App2
- localhost:8080/Web/...

Comment: i have not installed iis on my windows.. so i doubt i f i can start iis manager..

Comment: you must have some kind of web server installed if you are running an application on your local host?

Comment: Could be u are using the build in IIS in visual studio if developing in .net but once you close the app it should no longer be running

Comment: that's not the case.. even after i restart my system and open my browser and type "localhost:8080" it asks me for username and password.